# Calling Stored procedure inside a thread to update multiple records

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, procedure

I am trying to calla stored procedure for various unique entities . The stored procedure for a single entity takes about 33 secs. So I decided to call it using threads.

Here are some of trials I have done :

```
public bool ExecuteTaxRateLinkingParallel(int mapID, int createdBy)
{
    try
    {
        int snapshotID = (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session[GlobalConstant.snapShotID]);
        List<TaxEntity> taxEntities = new List<TaxEntity>();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        using (var ctx = new TopazDbContainer())
        {
            taxEntities = ctx.TaxEntities.AsParallel().Where(t => t.IsActive == true).ToList<TaxEntity>();
        }

        Parallel.ForEach<TaxEntity>(taxEntities, (entity) =>
        {
            //SqlConnection connection; SqlTransaction trans; SqlCommand command;
            // break this into pieces of 5
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var pctx = new TopazDbContainer())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int taxEntityID = entity.TaxEntityID;
                        pctx.CommandTimeout = 5000;
                        //string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TOPAZDBConnectionStringParallel"].ConnectionString;
                        //connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                        //command = new SqlCommand("dbo.[Usp_TaxRatesLinkingParallel]", connection);
                        //trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
                        //command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MapID", mapID);
                        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", createdBy);
                        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaxEntityID", taxEntityID);
                        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SnapshotID", snapshotID);
                        //connection.Open();
                        //command.CommandTimeout = 5000;
                        //command.ExecuteReader().AsParallel();

                        pctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

                        //pctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("Exec [Usp_TaxRatesLinkingParallel] @MapID={0},@UserID={1},@TaxEntityID={2},@SnapshotID{3}", new SqlParameter("MapID", mapID), new SqlParameter("UserID", createdBy), new SqlParameter("TaxEntityID", taxEntityID), new SqlParameter("SnapshotID", snapshotID));
                        var param = new DbParameter[] { new SqlParameter("UserID", createdBy), new SqlParameter("TaxEntityID", taxEntityID), new SqlParameter("SnapshotID", snapshotID) };
                        pctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("Exec [Usp_TaxRatesLinkingParallel] @MapID,@UserID,@TaxEntityID,@SnapshotID", param);

                        //var result = output.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    catch (TaskCanceledException tx)
                    {
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        pctx.SaveChanges();
                        pctx.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);

            tasks.Add(task);

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                ae.Handle((x) =>
                {
                    if (x is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TopazErrorLogs.AddTopazErrorLogBL(ex, 1, 1);
        throw new TopazCustomException(GlobalConstant.errorMessage);
    }
}
```

For some the above statements the SP seems like it runs fine but when I check from the application or from backend the records doesn't get updated.

Need help!

Comment: Why does the stored procedure take so long? Are you sure running it in parallel would actually help you?

Comment: Yes It will help us if we run it in parallel. It takes too long as it is inserting and updating several tables in a go.

Comment: Are you sure? If it takes this long, it's most likely either because the database server is waiting on its disk or because it's waiting on some database locks. And parallelization won't help you if that's the case.

Comment: I must admit the procedure is not optimal but it is not producing any locks.

Comment: you can use Sql Profiler to see if the sp runs for all your entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not on .NET 4.5 yet, you can use these extension methods to execute your commands async.

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace System.Data.SqlClient
{
    public static class SqlCommandExtensions
    {
        public static Task<SqlDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(this SqlCommand command)
        {
            Contract.Requires(command != null);
            return ExecuteReaderAsync(command, null);
        }

        public static Task<SqlDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(this SqlCommand command, object state)
        {
            Contract.Requires(command != null);
            return Task.Factory.FromAsync<SqlDataReader>(command.BeginExecuteReader, command.EndExecuteReader, state);
        }

        public static Task<XmlReader> ExecuteReaderXmlAsync(this SqlCommand command)
        {
            Contract.Requires(command != null);
            return ExecuteReaderXmlAsync(command, null);
        }

        public static Task<XmlReader> ExecuteReaderXmlAsync(this SqlCommand command, object state)
        {
            Contract.Requires(command != null);
            return Task.Factory.FromAsync<XmlReader>(command.BeginExecuteXmlReader, command.EndExecuteXmlReader, state);
        }

        public static Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(this SqlCommand command)
        {
            Contract.Requires(command != null);
            return ExecuteNonQueryAsync(command, null);
        }

        public static Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(this SqlCommand command, object state)
        {
            Contract.Requires(command != null);
            return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(command.BeginExecuteNonQuery, command.EndExecuteNonQuery, state);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And dont forget to add "Asynchronous Processing=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" to your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an asynchronous database query that you are doing here. Please have a look:

[Asynchronous Database Calls With Task-based Asynchronous Programming Model (TAP) in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronous-database-calls-with-task-based-asynchronous-programming-model-tap-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Here is an example of an asynchronous database call with new async / await features:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetCarsAsync() {

    var connectionString = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CarGalleryConnStr"].ConnectionString;

    var asyncConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString) {
        AsynchronousProcessing = true
    }.ToString();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(asyncConnectionString)) {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = selectStatement;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {

                return reader.Select(r => carBuilder(r)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may find the detailed info inside the blog post.

Comment: unfortunately the project is almost complete and we have used .Net 4.0 so I am afraid we cannot use async and await.